# Opening Nativescript app from notification does not alway go to last view

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm having an intermittent problem in which opening my Nativescript based app from a notification does not always take me to the last view the app was on when I minimized it. I'm currently experiencing this on Android 5.1.1.

I know that the Resume event is called when ever the app re-opens and I can put some logic in there to force a certain view to load but oddly it's not always a common problem. When opening the app from a notification, the resume event is hit, and then it just defaults to the start screen of my app. This is not what I want. Is this expected behavior? It doesn't seem like it is since it's intermittent but seems to be happening more often now.

Note: I'm using the Nativescript push plugin to handle client side notifications. I'm also still using NS 2.2.1 since there seemed to be some issues in 2.3 and @next

Comment: This is possibly related to this issue https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2852

Comment: @NickIliev Do you know if the issue you mention is apart of a newer version of NS only? I notice the issue you posted mentions that it occurred following a recent commit. Yet NS 2.2.1 was released much longer ago.

Comment: Honestly, I can not reproduce this issue at my side - my test app is coming back to the exact page at which it was suspended. However, if your case is that the app is destroyed and you want to reopen it from the push-notification on the last known state/page then it surely must be done with own specific logic (e.g. using the onDestroy event and saving the current state in app setting.. then with the notification use this app-settings)

Comment: @NickIliev in my case the application is not "destroyed" it's simply running in the background. The phone could be on the home screen, the notification comes in, user taps it and then the app opens to the starting page rather than to the last know view.